# Can I use a just part of the zend framework library?

Tags: php, zend-framework

Can I use just a part of the framework libraries. I think it is too bad to upload the whole framework and I'm using just few of its features. Or better yet, is there a tool to extract the needed libraries and make a standalone application from the framework?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go ahead and use parts of it! The rule of thumb would be to upload the whole **Zend/Form/** directory + **Zend/Form.php** if you want to use `Zend_Form` etc.

Beware of dependencies within though. This [list of internal dependencies](http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Framework/requirements.dependencies.html) appeared while googling for "zend framework dependency" but since it is quite out of context, I don't know for which version of ZF it applies too. *Disclaimer: framework.zend.com was unresponsive for me at the time of this post :)*